# Creating nested parent child array from one dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 array.

First Array:

```
$array = array( 
   'a' => 'b',
   'b' => 'c',
   'c' => 'd',
);
```

Second Array:

```
 $array =  Array
    (
        [a] => Array
            (
                [0] => b
                [1] => h
            )

        [b] => c
        [c] => d
        [h] => m
    )
```

i need to change this array  like

First array:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => Array
                        (
                            [d] => d
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Second Array:

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => Array
                        (
                            [d] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [h] => Array
                (
                    [m] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

sirwilliam answers helped for first array problem. and I need it for multi dimensional array. Help to resolve the problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: And what you have tried..

Comment: @Uchiha I tried with array_walk_recursive and used this function function myfunction($products, $value){
  foreach($products as $key => $product){
if ( $product === $value ){
return $key;
}else{
return $product;
}
  }
}

Comment: But what is `$value` over here

Comment: @Jegan you should not post code in comments, you should edit your question.

Comment: @Uchiha Just passed the array value in the foreach loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to use & (references):

**PHP:**

```
    $array = array( 
       'a' => 'b',
       'b' => 'c',
       'c' => 'd',
    );

    $newArray = array();
    $newArray[key($array)] = array();
    $part = &$newArray;

    foreach($array as $first => $second){
        $part = &$part[$first];
        $part[$second] = array();
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($newArray);
    echo "</pre>";

?>
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => Array
                        (
                            [d] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Then you can create a loop for the last part.

Comment: this is always starting at index 'a'... Is this desired behaviour?

Comment: What if there is `'cat' => 'over a tree',` ?

Comment: @sirwilliam If i have multi dimensional array?. Can you help me

Comment: If you have a new question ask new question