# Creating nested parent child array from multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have this array

```
$array =  Array
    (
        [a] => Array
            (
                [0] => b
                [1] => h
            )

        [b] => c
        [c] => d
        [h] => m
    )
```

And I need to convert the array to like below

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => Array
                        (
                            [d] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [h] => Array
                (
                    [m] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I already asked this question for One Dimensional array.

I tried with [[Creating nested parent child array from one dimensional array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755874/creating-nested-parent-child-array-from-one-dimensional-array-in-php]) and I got the below array

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [a] => Array
                        (
                            [h] => Array
                                (
                                    [b] => Array
                                        (
                                            [c] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [d] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                    [h] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [m] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

How to Check wheather the key is present in multi dimensional array and if present add the child to the existing key. Help to resolve the Problem. Thanks in Advance

Comment: I see, PHP is a wonderful language.

Comment: and you have some piece of code to show us?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer i Shared the stockoverflow link for the code

Comment: If I understand correctly, you first want all the keys of the first level as child element of the first entry, then the last element of each child array as child of the last element?

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php 

$array = array( 
   'a' => array(0=>'b',1=>'h'),
   'b' => 'c',
   'c' => 'd',
   'h' => 'm',
);

$newArray    = array();
$secondarray = array();
$part        = &$newArray;
$i=1;

foreach($array as $first => $second)
{
    if($i==1)
    {
        $firstone=$first;
    }
    else
    {
        if($i==count($array))
        {
            $newArray[$first] = array($second => array());
            $secondarray[$firstone]=$newArray;
        }
        else
        {
            $part = &$part[$first];
            $part[$second] = array();
         }
     }
     $i++;
}

echo '<pre>';print_r($secondarray);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [a] => Array
        (
            [b] => Array
                (
                    [c] => Array
                        (
                            [d] => Array
                                (
                                )

                        )

                )

            [h] => Array
                (
                    [m] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```